# Can't see my Total score for All time after changing profile

Tags: support, tag-score

In the beginning, I was able to find out my Total score for every tag in Stats tab (on stackoverflow.com). My score is not so large to be in the list, but it always was on the last place, so I could see it. And I thought it was designed to work in that way.

<del>After I changed my profile (changed Display Name) I can't see my Total score.</del>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems to be the only way is to find out Total score is to get into Top20. That's what I'm going to do.

Answer (score 2):

We no longer support this due to SQL timeouts on the queries.

Long story, but has to do with full text indexing and OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN not being compatible.

Comment: Is there the other way now to find out my Total score for specified tag?